# maven build failed for glassfish dependency

Tags: maven, glassfish, dependency-management, pom.xml

I'm getting the following error consistently on a Maven build. I can't figure out what's happening. What's the technical explanation?

```
Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.2/jersey-project-1.2.pom
185b downloaded  (jersey-project-1.2.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - RETRYING
Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.2/jersey-project-1.2.pom
185b downloaded  (jersey-project-1.2.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - IGNORING
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: null:jersey-server:bundle:null

Reason: Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey-server:bundle:null for project null:jersey-server:bundle:null


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar': Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey-server:bundle:null for project null:jersey-server:bundle:null
  com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.2
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us your `pom.xml` and make it easier for us to find out what's wrong?

Comment: You must give us your `pom.xml` and the repository settings from your `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

i met the same problem ,in fact ,the glassfish repository has been 301. so if we can use the central reposity first,there won't be these problems.  NOW my method is to modify the pom file which use the glassfish repository . Delete some lines about the repository. Then it can work this time.  BUT soon  another problem com ,So many pom contains the glassfish. And i modify the next. OH, too many.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your jersey-project pom file in you local repository
    ~/m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.2/jersey-project-1.2.pom
    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-project\1.2\jersey-project-1.2.pom

the POM content maybe incorrect, like following,

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.6.39</center>
</body>
</html
```

just delete the POM file(or just delet jersey directory), and re-try, you will fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248395/1122841

As suggested there I added mirroring details in settings.xml  (inside config directory of maven) 
deleted .m2/repository/com/sun/jersey  so that previously downloaded jars or poms are deleted
And built project again. It freshly downloaded all things successfully.