# Maven uses wrong repository to download

Tags: maven

I am using a bit older version (1.5) of com.sun.jersey-server/json/client and it has to be this version so please don't suggest to use a newer version.

In my pom.xml I am referencing it with:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- version conflicts with explicit direct dependency -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Compiling gives this output with error:

```xml
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building MediaAssistantWebService
    [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
    [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [...]
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    Downloading: http://repositories.dai-labor.de/extern/content/repositories/dai-open/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.5/jersey-server-1.5.pom
    [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:pom:1.5' in repository dai-open (http://repositories.dai-labor.de/extern/content/repositories/dai-open)
    Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2//com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.5/jersey-server-1.5.pom 10K downloaded  (jersey-server-1.5.pom)
    Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.5/jersey-project-1.5.pom 185b downloaded  (jersey-project-1.5.pom)
    [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html><head><title>301' - RETRYING
    Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.5/jersey-project-1.5.pom185b downloaded  (jersey-project-1.5.pom)
    [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html><head><title>301' - IGNORING
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

    Project ID: null:jersey-server:bundle:null

    Reason: Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey-server:bundle:null for project null:jersey-server:bundle:null
```

After searching for a solution, I added this repository to my pom so maven looks there first:

```xml
<repository>
  <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
  <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

But that didn't do anything. I deleted the `.m2/jersey` folder and tried `mvn clean compile` again. It still tries to download it from the glassfish-404 repository.

Does anyone know what I have to change so it will download properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to add repository of the maven central before others:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    ...
</repositories>
```

Better option would be setting up of the nexus server and getting rid of repository sections in pom files:
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/

Answer (score 5):

The only solution that worked for me was adding a mirror in settings.xml for the glassfish repository:

```
<mirror>
    <id>glassfish-mirror</id>
    <name>glassfish mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases</url>
    <mirrorOf>glassfish-repository</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

As explained [here](http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/2195/cant-build-nuxeo-source-nuxeo-webengine-jax-rs-jersey-server-error)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the pom that is references by jersey, it includes some repo from glassfish.org. 
http://download.java.net/maven/2//com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.5/jersey-server-1.5.pom

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>glassfish-repository</id>
        <name>Repository for Glassfish</name>
        <url>http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When the transitive dependencies are tried to download, the server sends a redirect response, hence you see checksum error in the log that you provided.

try this in browser:
http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.5/jersey-project-1.5.pom

I know this is not solution to your problem (and too cumbersome), but can you try to `mvn install` the dependencies needed for jerser-server 1.5 locally so that it does not try to download those?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding:

```
<repository>
    <id>maven-central</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

To my POM.xml worked fine

Comment: it should be https and not http