# Why am I getting Maven error: "Unable to determine if resource X exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish"?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

Whenever we execute our `site` goal in Maven, we get a long list of dependency-related errors in our console log. The errors appear to be generated during the Dependency report creation part of the build. All of the errors seem to be generated when resources are checked against the `http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish` repository. (There's also a strange JavaFX error in there, but we won't worry about that for now) ***The build does finish successfully.***

```
10:21:52 [INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report         --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7:dependencies
10:22:07 [ERROR] Artifact: com.oracle:javafx:jar:2.2.25 has no file.
10:22:09 [WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' is invalid - Repository 'spring-external' will be blacklisted.
10:22:10 [WARNING] The repository url 'http://download.oracle.com/maven' is invalid - Repository 'oracleReleases' will be blacklisted.
10:22:12 [ERROR] Unable to determine if resource com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.1.3:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
10:22:12 [ERROR] Unable to determine if resource com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.19.0:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
10:22:13 [ERROR] Unable to determine if resource com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:jar:v3-rev88-1.19.0:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
10:22:13 [ERROR] Unable to determine if resource com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:13.0:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
...
```

I did some research, and it seems that the repository URL listed is correct. I'm wondering if it could possibly be a bug in our Dependencies report plugin? Not really sure, suggestions or speculation are welcome at this point

**Edit:**
Posting verbose console output for one of these errors below:

```
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:13.0:compile exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to look for file: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish//com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/13.0/guava-jdk5-13.0.jar. Return code is: 301
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.resourceExists(LightweightHttpWagon.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.RepositoryUtils.dependencyExistsInRepo(RepositoryUtils.java:228)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.printArtifactsLocations(DependenciesRenderer.java:1311)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.renderSectionDependencyRepositoryLocations(DependenciesRenderer.java:756)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.renderBody(DependenciesRenderer.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReportRenderer.render(AbstractMavenReportRenderer.java:79)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.DependenciesReport.executeReport(DependenciesReport.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish - Session: Disconnecting  
http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish - Session: Disconnected
http://download.java.net/maven/2 - Session: Opened  
http://download.java.net/maven/2 - Session: Disconnecting  
http://download.java.net/maven/2 - Session: Disconnected
http://download.java.net/maven/1 - Session: Opened  
http://download.java.net/maven/1 - Session: Disconnecting  
http://download.java.net/maven/1 - Session: Disconnected
https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public - Session: Opened  
https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public - Session: Disconnecting  
https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public - Session: Disconnected
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 - Session: Opened  
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 - Session: Disconnecting  
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 - Session: Disconnected
http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish - Session: Opened
```

Answer (score 35):

You will need to disable the dependency location checking by simply adding `<dependency.locations.enabled>false</dependency.locations.enabled>` in the properties' section of your `pom.xml` as next:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <dependency.locations.enabled>false</dependency.locations.enabled>
</properties>
```

The default value is `true` for more details refer to the parameter [`dependencyLocationsEnabled`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html#dependencyLocationsEnabled).

Answer (score 8):

If some of the repos seems broken you can disable this checking with
`-Ddependency.locations.enabled=false`

Check this link 
https://whatiscomingtomyhead.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/if-your-maven-site-build-is-too-slow/

Answer (score 0):

If you check http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish or http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish//com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/13.0/guava-jdk5-13.0.jar (from the verbose log) you'll see that there really seems to be no content (404).

There might be something wrong with your repository setup in the `pom.xml`. You can try adding repo1 before the other repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    ...
</repositories>
```

Because most of the stuff is in the maven central repo anyway, it might be that you can remove all the repositories from the `pom.xml` (except the Spring repo, if you really use Spring stuff).

**See also:**

- [Maven uses wrong repository to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689953/maven-uses-wrong-repository-to-download)
- [Maven is not using repo1, it's going over to maven.glassfish.org and failing my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093428/maven-is-not-using-repo1-its-going-over-to-maven-glassfish-org-and-failing-my)

Answer (score 0):

The faulty feature seems to removed in later versions of maven site plugin. Use a recent version:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
      </plugin>
```

You may also want:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- possibly other plugins -->
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```